# Request paypal to capture the order interface, why always return error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID

Tags: c#, paypal

**This is the information returned by requesting paypal capture interface**

Request Interface：`https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture`

Response Info:

```
{\"name\":\"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND\",
 \"details\":[{\"location\":\"path\",
 \"issue\":\"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID\",
 \"description\":\"Specified resource ID does not exist. Please check the resource ID and try again.\"}],
 \"message\":\"The specified resource does not exist.\",
 \"debug_id\":\"692b9f3b8036e\",
 \"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID\",
 \"rel\":\"information_link\",\"method\":\"GET\"}]}
```

Sandbox environment is no problem

`Under normal circumstances, the request should be normal and the corresponding data should be returned`

[image]

Comment: Doc link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture

Comment: The URL you are POSTing to is `/v2/checkout/orders/{id}/capture`, correct? So it sounds like whatever you are providing for the `{id}` parameter doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the interface address is correct

Answer (score 0):

- When created, orders are valid for approval for 72 hours.
- Once approved by a payer, an order is valid for capture for 3 hours.
- Orders can only be approved and captured in the environment they were created in (sandbox or live/production).

Usage of an order ID outside these parameters will return an error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, seeing your reply gave me inspiration